# Regex to allow number with comma and proper validation

Tags: c#, regex

Having a hard time getting my regex to work correctly. Essentially, all I need is a valid number regex that just allows for one comma. Here's what I have tried:

`[0-9]*[,]\\d`

(This was when I thought I might have a number with multiple commas, not the case anymore)

`[0-9][,]\\d`

and

`^\d+(?:[\,]\d+)?$` (http://regexr.com/3ggn5)

The latter seemed to work the best, however when I input this: `1,23134` it doesn't break the rule. How can I make it better to make sure if you input an invalid number `1,23232` (for example) it will break, but be fine if you do `1,232` (for example, just showing a valid number input).

**UPDATE**

This is the code surrounding, just using a RegularExpression annotation:

`[RegularExpression(@"^\d+(?:[\,]\d+)?$", ErrorMessage = ...]`

**UPDATE 2**

By valid number I simply mean a number that is correctly formatted to United States standards. Example of valid numbers:

- 1
- 10
- 100
- 1,000
- 1000
- 10,000
- 10000
- 100,000
- 100000
  ..etc

In the United States, we either have a comma or don't after the third digit sequentially (except for the first number in some cases, `1,000` is valid). Although, if you have comma, you typically will use commas every third digit. So I would assume a number like this: 1,00000000 isn't `valid`.

Examples of invalid numbers:

- 1,1
- 1,00
- 12,12

Basically if anywhere else in the world uses a comma in a place that isn't after the third digit, this would be invalid for what I need. Simply just numbers that may or may not have a comma.

Comment: How do you process the regex in C#? Please write the C# code surrounding it.

Comment: Do you want to allow just 1 to 3 digits after `,`? Then use `^\d+(?:,\d{1,3})?$`

Comment: This would only validate the number as you expect for those that use a comma decimal separator, you should just parse the number instead

Comment: Can you put some samples of valid and invalid data?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I will try this, thanks.

Comment: @FedericoPiazza I did? I just want it to make sure it's a valid number. `1,323232` is not a valid number, right? `1,323` is a valid number. Just clarifying.

Comment: Does it really have to be a regex? Or can you also just parse to float/double using `double.TryParse`?

Comment: @HimBromBeere If it was my decision this would be done client side with a simple `string.replace(',', ' ')` and be done with it, but this is being done via ASP.NET Annotations

Comment: I think you want something like this: `^\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*$`

Comment: You could increase the quality of your question by being more specific on what a well formatted number would be for you

Comment: @UlysseBN Sorry, it was my ignorance that assumed people around the world understood what `valid number` means. It appears that in the US, it's different then the rest of the world so my apologies, will edit it to make it more specific. Thanks.

Comment: No worries, it is way better now:+1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This Regex](https://regex101.com/r/pN6fR2/1) will parse a number in many *valid* format:

```
^-?(\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)?(\.\d+)?$
```

- It will detect too many numbers after comma
- wrong dot notation
- numbers with *no comma* will pass

If you don't need nor negative nor float numbers, you can simplify it:

```
^(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)$
```

And if you don't want number without comma either (e.g: 1345):

```
^\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+$
```

**P.S:** For users coming from a non-english speaking world, you can replace the comma with a space in all those regex, and it will work the same way

Comment: Wow, nice this seems really good. Let me test this out.